# Issue signing a file using Jsign and SafeNet eToken

Tags: code-signing

I am trying to follow this guide to sign the Windows executable installer generated by electron-builder on Mac: https://www.electron.build/tutorials/code-signing-windows-apps-on-unix#signing-windows-app-on-maclinux-using-jsign

I downloaded and installed the SafeNet Authentication Client, and can confirm the path to the `libeToken.dylib` exists. I created the `.cfg` file as instructed. Running the command with debug info enabled I get the following output:

```
$ java -Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11 -jar jsign-4.2.jar --keystore hardwareToken.cfg --storepass NONE --storetype PKCS11 --tsaurl http://timestamp.digicert.com --alias path/to/cert.pem path/to/installer.exe

SunPKCS11 loading hardwareToken.cfg
sunpkcs11: Initializing PKCS#11 library /usr/local/lib/libeToken.dylib
Information for provider SunPKCS11-HardwareToken
Library info:
  cryptokiVersion: 2.20
  manufacturerID: SafeNet, Inc.                   
  flags: 0
  libraryDescription: SafeNet eToken PKCS#11          
  libraryVersion: 9.01
All slots: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
Slots with tokens: (none)
jsign: Couldn't sign path/to/installer.exe
java.security.ProviderException: Failed to create a SunPKCS11 provider from the configuration hardwareToken.cfg
    at net.jsign.ProviderUtils.createSunPKCS11Provider(ProviderUtils.java:52)
[...]
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: slotListIndex is 0 but token only has 0 slots
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:363)
    ... 13 more
```

It's clear it doesn't like there not being a token in slot 0, but honestly I don't know what that means in this context. The docs from above only mention the following regarding it:

> Make sure you use the correct PKCS 11 engine and module. If you get no slot with a token was found or some errors like sc connect card error and Card is invalid or cannot be handled you are not using the correct module, make sure you use correct one.

However, it doesn't really specify what this "correct module" is. I kind of feel like I might be missing a step here?

Any advice would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: `slotListIndex` doesn't work when `java.security.debug` is set. Try using `slot` instead, and remove `-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11`.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to the latest version of Jsign the SunPKCS11 configuration is now automatically guessed when using the `ETOKEN` keystore type:

```
jsign --storetype ETOKEN --storepass <password> path/to/installer.exe
```